# extract columns from file based on list of header from 2nd file

Tags: awk

I have a big data file with many headers and the file is space delimited ( no tab or comma). I have another text file with single column of the desired headers. the headers contains numbers and letter. I am trying to use awk to extract those headers and print in a new file
data file (all.cov):

```
FID IID 80.09   E45.32
1621    1621    0   0
1622    1622    1   0
1623    1623    0   0
1624    1624    0   1
1625    1625    0   0
```

header file (all20.txt):

```
FID
IID
401.9
272.4
E45.32
80.09
```

I try few internet command using awk with no success such as below. it seems that the program is working but doesn't print anything:

```
awk -F' ' 'NR==FNR{arr[$1]++;next}{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in arr){a[i]++;}} { for (i in a) printf "%s[ ]", $i; printf "\n"}' all20.txt all.cov > test.txt
```

please help!

Comment: Please add the **expected output** for clear visualisation.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples only).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i in a){
       printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)
       array[i]
    }
    else{
       if(i==NF){
         print ""
       }
    }
  }
  next
}
{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    printf("%s%s",j in array?$j:"",j==NF?ORS:OFS)
  }
}
'  headers_file all.cov
```

---

---

***Logical explanation of code:***

- Read Input_file which has headers information in it, save information for all elements into an array.
- Now read the main Input_file, put specific condition for Very first line in Input_file.
- Loop through all elements(in header/1st line) and keep checking whichever element is present in array(made while reading headers file/1st step).
- Whichever element is present in array, now put its index(FIELD NUMBER) into new array(which will be used in all other lines then).
- Use printf command  where put 1 condition to check if field number is present in array(created in previous line) then print it else leave it.

Comment: Thank you...it seems to be working and add data but when I open the result file it is empty but it shows size

Comment: can you  also make all in one line ( I am getting syntax error), thanks

Comment: @motor30, technically, this is a shell one-liner. Also notice the filenames are different from yours.

Comment: yes, I changed those and  try to print it in a result file in last line : headers_file all.cov > result.txt     so the result is empty but it has a large size!

Comment: after I change the file to dos2unix, it is working now but the result file has unequal space between columns...can you look again and modify the formula? thanks

Comment: @motor30, Glad that solutions helped you, you could select any answer out of these as correct one too, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Similar in concept to @RavinderSingh13's, but simpler:

```sh
awk '
    NR == FNR { header[$0]=1; next }
    FNR == 1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in header) wanted[i]=1
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i in wanted) printf "%s ", $i
        print ""
    }
' all20.txt all.cov | column -t
```

Remove the pipe to `column -t` if you don't need it.

Comment: thanks but it just gives empty result file :   all20.txt all.cov | column -t > result.txt

Comment: Make sure your all20 file does not have DOS-style line endings. The trailing `\r` will ensure that **no headers** in all.cov match.